# Skipping ORM validation in Kohana 3.3

Tags: orm, kohana

How can I skip validation for a specific orm save on without uprooting my ORM models rules function?

I am using kohana 3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into `rules()` method. You can easily add custom checks, like this one:

```
// required by default
protected $_validation_required = TRUE;

public function rules()
{
    if ($this->validation_required())
    {
         // return all model rules
         return array(
              // default rules here
         );
         // or 
         // if extending model with existing rules
         return parent::rules(); 
    }
    else
    {
         // skip validation 
         return array();
    }
}

public function validation_required($required = TRUE)
{
     if ($required === NULL)
     {
           // work as getter
           return $this->_validation_required;
     }

     // set value
     $this->_validation_required = (bool)$required;
     return $this;
}
```

Of course, you can extend this code with custom rules for different events (insert/update etc).

**PS**. Also you can override `check()` method and just return `TRUE` when `$this->validation_required() == TRUE`. But I'd preffer to send empty rules instead (cause `rules()` was designed specially for customize, while `check()` is a system method).

Comment: Thanks... Is there really no built in way todo it?

Comment: This IS built in way )) In previous versions rules were defined as property. With special `rules()` method Validation becomes more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

In accepted answer, the use of $this->validation_required() function like à getter seems wrong (the default value of  $required parameter is != NULL)

```
public function validation_required($required = TRUE)
{
    if ($required === NULL)
    {
       // work as getter
       return $this->_validation_required;
    }
...
```